# Как сделать определение мата в чате? telegram (aiogram или telebot)

Tags: telebot

Делаю тг бота должен реагировать на маты сообщением, но при этом не удалять сообщения просто отправлять сообщения что он сматернулся.

Comment: Вам нужны middleware из aiogram

Answer (score 0):

```
maty = ['mat', 'mat2'..] # здесь пишешь все маты

@bot.message_handler()
async def filter(msg: types.Message):
    is_mat = None
    for mat in maty:
        if mat in msg.text.lower(): # lower() делает все буквы прописными
            is_mat = True
            break
    if is_mat:
        await msg.reply('не матерись!') # здесь действие если есть маты в тексте
```